# How to make TypeScript complain about a mismatch with the **first** generic parameter rather than the second?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write a sort of "validation framework" in TypeScript as follows:

```
interface RawEvent {
  untrustedInput: string;
}

interface ValidatedEvent<T> {
  data: T;
};

type Response = void;
type RawHandler = (event: RawEvent) => Response;
type ValidatedHandler<T> = (event: ValidatedEvent<T>) => Response;
type ValidatorCallback<T> = (input: unknown) => input is T;

export function wrapHandler<T>(
  handler: ValidatedHandler<T>,
  validator: ValidatorCallback<T>
): RawHandler {
  return (event: RawEvent) => {
    const data: unknown = JSON.parse(event.untrustedInput);
    const dataIsValid = validator(data);
    if (dataIsValid) {
      return handler({data});
    }
  };
}
```

The idea being that I can provide a "handler" function which will only be called if the "validator" function is happy with the input.

But this runs into a problem. When there is a mismatch, e.g.

```
export const handler = wrapHandler(
  (evt: ValidatedEvent<number>) => {},
  (d): d is string { return typeof d === "string"; }
);
```

I would want it to complain that the **first** parameter is incorrect, because my handler is expecting a `number` but should be expecting a `string`. However, it instead complains that my *second* parameter is incorrect.

I think this is also related to why I can't provide a default "no data" validator like:

```
export function wrapHandler<T>(
  handler: ValidatedHandler<T>,
  validator?: ValidatorCallback<T> = (_): _ is void => true
): RawHandler
```

and it complains of:

> 'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.

instead of simply only allowing a `ValidatedHandler<void>` to be passed!

Is there a way to control the "precedence" as it were of multiple generic parameters?

Comment: You could create another generic parameter that extends the first one like in [here](https://tsplay.dev/WK3LGW). However, you will need to use assertion to remove the error `could be instantiated with an arbitrary type `

Answer (score 1):

You can mess with the order of inference by making a new generic parameter depend on the first.

```
export function wrapHandler<T, U extends T = T>(
  handler: ValidatedHandler<U>,
  validator: ValidatorCallback<T>
): RawHandler {
  return (event: RawEvent) => {
    const data: unknown = JSON.parse(event.untrustedInput);
    const dataIsValid = validator(data);
    if (dataIsValid) {
      return handler({data: data as U});
    }
  };
}
```

Here you can take a second generic `U` that `extends T` and is equal to `T` by default.

Now `validator: ValidatorCallback<T>` uses the primary generic, and then `handler: ValidatedHandler<U>` has a `U` that must extend that.

However the `as U` kind of sucks, but without it:

```
`Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'.
  'U' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.(2322)
```

Which makes sense, because now you could technically call this with:

```
wrapHandler<{ a: number }, { a: number, b: number }>(...)
```

Maybe you could prefix that type with `_` like `_U` to inform people to not ever do that.

But good news is thanks to the `= T` part, you only have to pass it one generic if you want to be explicit:

```
wrapHandler<{ a: number }>(...)
```

---

This works as follows:

```
wrapHandler(
  (evt: ValidatedEvent<number>) => {}, // error here
  (d): d is string => { return typeof d === "string"; }
);

wrapHandler(
  (evt: ValidatedEvent<string>) => {},
  (d): d is string => { return typeof d === "string"; }
); // fine
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEpwO4FEBuFzIDeAUMsgK7hTkDOkAJgJIgAO5YAXMnVKAOYBuYgF9ixUJFiIUANTgAbYPTgNc+MAB4AKgD4ipZMrBwuWocKHEwATxYpUEGiwD2IGigC8yHM6VCbdmiYABJwIPTy0MheABQQeOBc6NgJYACU0XoOTq7u-rayCkoqEPSh4ZFQ2nqx8epccopGpWrg1RkeWY4ubhD5gY3FYM5QAMIK8gBGiADW1dHIMaBsnBQgMyDOGCAdesvsyMA0yGZiEAAeLlBgyDCUCGDArsgYUHAs5RHQ2gA0yAD6AFVkBdIOFjloFroYgYABZhL5QBpFZplBGVDRAnQ-Aw4FEqEbIpoEsYTaYIOa6YhpJIhdFREhkKAQMDkKAgRZ1RJBFLqXb6MhkBC5G5GExrDZbDleABSAGUAPIAOQAdCw4FB3HFUirKGBqHRSswVmkhILkMK3KKVHBGDRBvQFnjicMoDExaaDGRgDBFmK7Q6Mozzchmaz2ch4RVoDFCGKuGLkHBjkDhJ7zaIyBYRGJXu9PpUYWRtasHSV6K1NCByABbSbQHT8wjCP4AelbIKgUBGkegEAM7pphkOxx4-EyRFDLLZHICEGcvsdHmXyAARGOQHxVwJkKJPcQ8x96W6B-FS-jVKkNBu+I2J82ccX6EPHUduPrx51J2GZ8g5wvh2XLx1w-Tdt13akd3bW5QAgIA)

Comment: "*now you could technically call this with wrong type parameters*" - they also could just be inferred, like from `wrapHandler((evt: ValidateEvent<"oops">) => {…}, (d): d is string => {…})`, which is wrong but compiles. Not sure if this can be solved.